# WPF:SelectedItem Binding at ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I have a Problem with the ComboBox at wpf and xaml. The ItemsSource of my combobox is a custom class (Contacts.cs). If I type a string (length > 2) it DropDownList should only contain the Items which contains my entered substring. This works great. But know I have an other problem. I explain it with an example:

1. select one Item (Testi2)
2. delete the last character (Testi)
3. the drop down opens the itemssource shows all Items containing "Testi"
4. Textbox shows Testi2
5. expected Result: Textbox shows Testi

I think there is something wrong with the SelectedItem, but I don't know how to fix it.

An image of the behavior of the combobox
http://postimg.org/image/dl2s4iggn/

Contacts.cs

```
namespace Test.Model
{
class Contacts
{
    private string name;
    private string age;

    public Contacts(string name, string age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Contacts()
    {
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }
}
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<custom:CustomComboBox x:Name="CustomCombo"
   Grid.Row="1" 
   Grid.Column="1"
   ItemsSource="{Binding CustomContacts}"
   SelectedItem="{Binding CustomSelectedContact}" 
   DisplayMemberPath="Name"
   Margin="5"
   IsEditable="True"
   IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
   KeyUp="CustomComboBox_KeyUp"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
   Grid.Column="2"
   Margin="10,5,5,0”
   VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <Run Text="{Binding CustomSelectedContact.Name}"/>
          <Run Text=" - "/>
          <Run Text="{Binding CustomSelectedContact.Age}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

MainWindow.caml.cs

```
namespace Test.View
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void CustomComboBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CustomCombo.Text.Length < 3)
            return;

        var viewModel = (MainWindowViewModel)DataContext;
        viewModel.CustomSearchParameter = CustomCombo.Text;
        CustomCombo.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }

}
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
namespace Test.ViewModel
{
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Contacts> customcontacts;
    private Contacts customselectedContact;
    private string customsearchParameter;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        customcontacts = new ObservableCollection<Contacts>();
        customcontacts.Add(new Contacts("Test", "asdf"));
        customcontacts.Add(new Contacts("Testi1", "iasdf"));
        customcontacts.Add(new Contacts("Testi2", "ijkl"));
        customcontacts.Add(new Contacts("Testo", "o"));
        customcontacts.Add(new Contacts("Testo2", "oasdf"));
        customcontacts.Add(new Contacts("Other", "otherasdf"));
        customselectedContact = new Contacts();
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Contacts> CustomContacts
    {
        get
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomSearchParameter))
            {
                ObservableCollection<Contacts> temp = new ObservableCollection<Contacts>();
                foreach (Contacts contact in customcontacts)
                {
                    if (contact.Name.Contains(CustomSearchParameter))
                    {
                        temp.Add(contact);
                    }
                }
                return temp;
            }
            return customcontacts;
        }
        set { customcontacts = value; }
    }

    public Contacts CustomSelectedContact
    {
        get { return customselectedContact; }
        set
        {
            customselectedContact.Name = value.Name;
            customselectedContact.Age = value.Age;
            OnPropertyChanged("CustomSelectedContact");
        }
    }

    public string CustomSearchParameter
    {
        get { return customsearchParameter; }
        set
        {
            customsearchParameter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CustomContacts");
        }
    }
}
}
```

CustomComboBox.cs

```
namespace Test.CustomWindowsControls
{
class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

            this.DropDownOpened += comboBox_DropDownOpened;
    }

    void comboBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var element = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox");
        if (element != null)
        {
            var txt = (TextBox)element;

            if (base.IsDropDownOpen && txt.SelectionLength > 0)
            {
                txt.CaretIndex = base.Text.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the SelectedItem property to 'customselectedContact' which represents the current selected object from the combo. When the end user filters the list, an object is selected so the text of the textbox changes.

A quick fix would be to do:

```
Text="{Binding CustomSearchParameter}"
```

Comment: fantastic. Thank you. I had a work around with CustomCombo.SelectedIndex = -1;CustomCombo.Text = viewModel.CustomSearchParameter;